# Setting hadoop.tmp.dir on Windows gives error: URI has an authority component

Tags: windows, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to specify the base directory for HDFS files in my `hdfs-site.xml` under Windows 7 (Hadoop 2.7.1 that I built from source, using Java SDK 1.8.0_45 and Windows SDK 7.1). I can't figure how to provide a path that specifies a drive.

My `hdfs-site.xml` looks like this:

`<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>XXX</value>
  </property>
</configuration>`

and I tried various values for `XXX`, which I tested with `hdfs namenode -format`, all leading to one of these 2 errors:

- `XXX=D:/tmp/hdp`:

  `15/07/10 23:38:33 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
      at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.getStorageDirectory(NNStorage.java:329)`
- `XXX=D:\tmp\hdp`: `ERROR common.Util: Syntax error in URI file://D:\tmp\hdp/dfs/name`

Other variants that gave similar errors: `file:///D:/tmp/hdp` (from http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/hadoop-configuration-files-issues/), `file://D:/tmp/hdp`, `D:\\tmp\\hdp`

And if I use `/D/tmp/hdp` it does not crash, but goes into a `D` folder on my current drive.

I'm out of ideas, any suggestion? (NB: besides using Cygwin, which is not an option for me)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify a drive spec in `hadoop.tmp.dir` in core-site.xml by prepending a '/' in front of the absolute path, and using '/' as the path separator instead of '\' for all path elements.  For example, if the desired absolute path is D:\tmp\hdp, then it would look like this:

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/D:/tmp/hdp</value>
</property>
```

The reason this works is that the default values for many of the HDFS directories are configured to be `file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/suffix`.  See the default definitions of `dfs.namenode.name.dir`, `dfs.datanode.data.dir` and `dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir` here:

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml

Substituting the above value for `hadoop.tmp.dir` yields a valid `file:` URI with a drive spec and no authority, which satisfies the requirements for the HDFS configuration.  It's important to use '/' instead of '\', because a bare unencoded '\' character is not valid in URL syntax.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

If you prefer not to rely on this substitution behavior, then it's also valid to override all configuration properties that make use of `hadoop.tmp.dir` within your hdfs-site.xml file.  Each value must be a full `file:` URI.  For example:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///D:/tmp/hdp/dfs/name</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///D:/tmp/hdp/dfs/data</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
    <value>file:///D:/tmp/hdp/dfs/namesecondary</value>
</property>
```

You might find this more readable overall.